# Using Roslyn how do I update the class using directives?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Just discovering Roslyn, so please be patient.

I would like to update the using directives at the top of my class to include an additional statment, for example:

```
using System;

public class Foo {

}
```

Should become:

```
using System;
using Custom.Bar;

public class Foo {

}
```

I see that I can override `SyntaxRewriter` and I have done this to address method level code, but I can't see an override that might give me access to these using directives?

Thanks.

Edit:

I have found this property, but I don't know how to modify it.

```
var tree = document.GetSyntaxTree().GetRoot() as SyntaxNode;

var compilationUnitSyntax = (CompilationUnitSyntax) (tree);

if (compilationUnitSyntax != null)
      compilationUnitSyntax.Usings.Add();
```

Unfortunately UsingDirectiveSyntax is internal so how can I add one! :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To create `SyntaxNodes` you must use the `Syntax` class factory methods in your case the `Syntax.UsingDirective` method.

And you can add a new using with the `AddUsings` method  something like

```
if (compilationUnitSyntax != null)
{
    var name = Syntax.QualifiedName(Syntax.IdentifierName("Custom"),
                                    Syntax.IdentifierName("Bar"));
    compilationUnitSyntax = compilationUnitSyntax
        .AddUsings(Syntax.UsingDirective(name).NormalizeWhitespace());
}
```

Note: because of the immutability of the `CompilationUnitSyntax` you need to reassign your `compilationUnitSyntax` variable with the result of the `AddUsings` call.

Comment: For creating things like `QualifiedNameSyntax`, it's sometimes easier to use Syntax.ParseName, instead of building all the parts directly.

Comment: I dont get why there are 3 ways available that give the impression you can add something to an object. (`cus.Usings.Add()  cus.AddUsings()  cus.WithUsings()`) and only one of them actually gives a hint that the object is immutable..

Comment: I didn't know about `NormalizeWhitespace()`! Thank you!

Comment: `Syntax` should be replaced by `SyntaxFactory`.